# Regular Expression - Get specific group value in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following regular expression problem.

Input:

```
123_321_009
3111_00_001
5123_123
555
666_A66
777_B77_777
```

Output request as below:

```
123_321
3111_00
5123
555
666_A66
777_B77
```

Is there any way to get the value of the output above?

I tried below statement but lack the idea how to get the value i needed.

```
^(.*?)\\s?([_0-9])?$
```

Value appearing after the last underscore are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you a using Oracle, you can use a `regex_replace(val,pattern,'')` function with this pattern.

The following patterns would satisfy the samples you provided:

`_[0-9]{3}$`

`_[0-9]*$`

Here is a demonstration of this approach using SQL*Plus:

```
 SCOTT@dev> WITH tab(num_val) AS
      2    ( SELECT '123_321_009' FROM dual
      3    UNION ALL
      4    SELECT '3111_00_001' FROM dual
      5    UNION ALL
      6    SELECT '5123_123' FROM dual
      7    UNION ALL
      8    SELECT '555' FROM dual
      9    )
     10  SELECT tab.num_val,
     11    regexp_replace(tab.num_val,'_[0-9]{3}$') approach_1,
     12    regexp_replace(tab.num_val,'_[0-9]*$') approach_2
     13  FROM tab
     14  /

    NUM_VAL     APPROACH_1             APPROACH_2
    =========== ====================== ==================
    123_321_009 123_321                123_321
    3111_00_001 3111_00                3111_00
    5123_123    5123                   5123
    555         555                    555
```

If you provided a larger sampling (or a more specific rule), a more specific solution could be provided.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a bit on your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE to remove the numbers following/including the last underscore.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/2532)

**Query**:

```
with x(y) as (
  select '123_321_009' from dual union all
  select '3111_00_001' from dual union all
  select '5123_123' from dual union all
  select '666_A66' from dual union all
  select '777_B77_777' from dual union all
  select '555' from dual
)
select y, regexp_replace(y,'_\d+$') substr
from x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/2532/0)**:

```
|           Y |  SUBSTR |
|-------------|---------|
| 123_321_009 | 123_321 |
| 3111_00_001 | 3111_00 |
|    5123_123 |    5123 |
|     666_A66 | 666_A66 |
| 777_B77_777 | 777_B77 |
|         555 |     555 |
```

Pattern:

```
_       --matches an underscore
\d+     --matches one or more numbers
$       --matches end of the string
```

Effectively, this matches all the digits following/including the last underscore. Third parameter is regexp_replace is omitted. So, the pattern is
removed and replaced by nothing.

Comment: since i have added 2 more condition, so that i tried to put "REGEXP_REPLACE(input,'_[^_A-Z]+$') AS OUTPUT_B" from your idea, and i got the answer i needed... thank you again...